# model diagnostic using plot(model) in r: return the suspicious values

Tags: model, lm, diagnostic

plot(model) gives us a number of diagnostic plots with regards to the model we build. In these plots, if there are suspicious values (values which might decrease model performance), their index is printed on-plot. Is it possible to return these indexes on the console? [image]

Comment: Check the `id.n` argument in the plot function, `number of points to be labelled in each plot, starting with the most extreme.`.

Comment: This lets me control the number of values which will be labelled in each plot. However, what I want is: these values to be printed out in the console too. Not just the plot. In the figure I attached above: I want the values 180 and 191 to be printed out in the console.